# What would be this SOAP request in php (adding an object)

Tags: php, soap

I admit to being a bit confused. I need to convert the below SOAP (.net I presume) into a php call (It is to integrate with Checkmarx - https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/display/KC/Initiating+a+Session):

```
public void LogAdminIn()
{
    CxSDKWebServiceSoapClient cxSDKProxy = new CxSDKWebServiceSoapClient();
    CxWSResponseLoginData loginResult = cxSDKProxy.Login(new Credentials() { User = "admin@cx", Pass = "admin" }, 1033);
sessionID = loginResult.SessionId;
}
```

This was my attempt:

```
$client = new SoapClient($ServiceURL); 
$param = array(
    'User' => $login,
    'Pass' => $password,
    'lcid' => "1033"
); 
$result = $client->Login(new SoapParam ($param, "Credentials"));
var_dump($result);
```

But I have no confidence it is actually right (it doesn't work, so I suppose it isn't).

I am presuming the structure, but confused as to what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enabled soap in the php.ini file ?

`extension=php_soap.dll` remove the ;

and add in your script :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', '0');
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', '0');
```

And you need some try catch as well :

```
try {
    $client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl");
    $result = $client->SomeFunction(/* ... */);
} catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Check that and maybe you will have some hints :)

Comment: The soap part of this does work, it connects and the soap service returns an error - says it is a general error and looks like it is permissions related.  It looks to me that I haven't formatted the parameters correctly, the new SoapParam bit.  I am not sure I am doing that correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Login() method takes two parameters: a Credentials structure and an integer.  You just need to change things slightly:

```
$credentials = array('User' => $login, 'Pass' => $password);
$lcid = 1033;
$result = $client->Login($credentials, $lcid);
```

If that doesn't work, you could also try making $credentials an object:

```
$credentials = new stdClass();
$credentials->User = $login;
$credentials->Pass = $password;
$lcid = 1033;
$result = $client->Login($credentials, $lcid);
```

After making the call, it is helpful to inspect the actual call for the XML and make sure the request is proper:

```
var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
```